# elements inserted in the linked list is not being displayed

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am trying to create and insert into singly linked list with 2 nodes by calling a user defined function insert and display using user defined display function. Expected output:- 5 10
Output i'm getting is:=5 
please help.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

struct list
{
    int data;
    struct list *link;
};
struct list *start=NULL;
int insert(int a)
{
    struct list *n,*t,*p;
    n= new list;
    n->data=a;
    n->link=NULL;
    if(start==NULL)
    {
        start=n;
    }
    else if(start!=NULL)
    {
        t=start;
        while(t->link!=NULL)
        {
            t=t->link;
        }
        t->link=n;
    }
    return(0);
}
int Display(struct list *p)
{ 

    while(p->link!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<p->data;
        p=p->link;
    }
    return(0);

}
int main()
{  
   insert(5);
   insert(10);
   Display(start);
   return(0);
}
```

Comment: `while (p->link != NULL)` -- Why are you testing if the link is NULL?  Ask yourself what you should be testing in that `while` loop.  If you changed the name from `link` to `next`, maybe you will see the error.

Comment: Populate start node correctly there are proplems in insert()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Display` function, replace `while(p->link!=NULL)` by `while(p != NULL)`. Otherwise, you are not printing data of last Node.

Answer (score 0):

The order is important. First print the node data and then traverse the link.
With your code once you were in the last node you would print not the data because that node would not have a link, and that is incorrect.

```
int Display(struct list *p)
{ 
    cout<<p->data;
    while(p->link!=NULL)
    {
        p=p->link;
        cout<<p->data;
    }
    return(0);

}
```